# wcf configuration in app.config and hard-coded

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF service: app.config versus attributes or a mixture of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761105/wcf-service-app-config-versus-attributes-or-a-mixture-of-both)

can i override the hard coded configuration with the app.config configuration?

for example, i have this hard coded configuration:

```
[ServiceBehavior(TransactionTimeout = "00:02:00")]
public class DateTimeService : IDateTimeService
{
    //....
}
```

and i want to override this with app.config configuration, like this:

```
<serviceBehaviors >
    <behavior name ="DateTimeService_serviceBehavior">
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout ="00:01:00"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

is it possible ? also, is it possible to merge those configurations in case of different elements?

Comment: This should answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761105/wcf-service-app-config-versus-attributes-or-a-mixture-of-both